# If $a|(b-c)$ does it follow that $a|(b+c)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

I plug in numbers and this seems to work but how can this be proved? If: $a|(b-c)\space \rightarrow\space ak=b-c$, but I can't see how this would mean $a|(b+c)$

If this is true, how can this be proved?

Comment: It is not true, for example: $5|6-1$, bus $5\nmid 6+1$.

Comment: Another example that does not work: $a=337, b=2345, c=323$.

Comment: You should have plugged in more numbers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$7$ divides $0=3-3$ but doesn't divide $3+3=6$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\rm\ \ a\mid b-c\,\ \Rightarrow\,\ mod\ a\!:\ b\equiv c\ \Rightarrow\ b+c\equiv 2c,\ $ so $\rm\,\ a\mid b+c\iff a\mid 2c$

Answer (score 0):

Just writing this very quickly. Someone correct me if I am wrong. You can maintain the difference $b-c$ constant by adding $n$ to both $b$ and $c$. So let's suppose $a\equiv 0 \pmod{b-c}.$ Then is true also that $a\equiv 0 \pmod{b+n-c-n}.$. But if the original theory is true that it must hold that $a\equiv 0 \pmod{b+c+2n}.$ But if $(b+c)$ has $a$ as a factor then also $2n$ must. But I can choose $n$ prime and then I have a contradiction.

But I guess this is redundant since once we have a numerical proof that should be enough. Altough not elegant ;-)

Comment: $a\mid(b-c)$ means $b-c$ is zero mod $a$. You have it backwards.